# Selenium Java Reuse Browser Session

Tags: selenium, firefox, reusability

I'm new to Java and Selenium and have this issue where I need to reuse the browser session.

I've searched around, but could not find a good solution for that.
Is there a way to reuse Firefox session in Selenium with Java?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Save your cookies and retrieve them at each creation of the driver

   ```
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   for(Cookie cookie : allCookies)
   {
       driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
   }
   ```
2. Save your browser profile locally and then load it

   ```
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
   File profileDirectory = new File("c://mach//lib//prof");
   FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(profileDirectory);
   capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
   ```

Comment: Tx for the help but, how about saving firefox profile or saving cookies? I'm not able to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried saving the cookies as a set: `Set<Cookie> cookies = driver.manage().getCookies();` and then retrieving them? Firefox saves profiles into a tmp folder which then gets deleted at shutdown, but you can still go into this tmp folder and save the profile in a file before. Reference here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30435749/python-selenium-firefox-cant-start-firefox-with-specified-profile-path/33350778#33350778. Alternatively, you can do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033071/save-firefox-profile-generated-by-selenuim-web-driver

Comment: when I try the code above for the cookies, I get ther error "allCookies cannot be resolved to a variable" any idea?

Comment: This error is becaouse I put the 'Set<Cookie> cookies = driver.manage().getCookies();' line when I want it to save the cookies... I  thought that it should be inserted right befor the 'driver.quit' so, all cookies wold be saved befor closing the browser.

Comment: change the variable name from allCookie to cookies or viceversa (-: